# Get Index Question - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select element by index (multiple elements of same class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311561/select-element-by-index-multiple-elements-of-same-class)

Quick question, I'm targeting all the article elements in my html5 page using:

```
var articles = $("article");
```

What I want to do is target one of the article elements using an index only. I can't seem to get it to work, any ideas?:

```
articles[1].css("display", "none");  // <-- This won't work
```

Comment: jQuery has a good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ You can even filter it by typing in the *Search in jQuery* box. Searching for `index` gives you a list of related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to target a specific index,

```
$("article").eq(1).css("display", "none");
```

According to the jQuery documentation referenced above,

> Reduce the set of matched elements to
>   the one at the specified index.

Answer (score 4):

The array is returning the DOM element rather than the jQuery object. The [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function does not exist on the DOM element, so you can wrap it in with the jQuery `$` function to create a jQuery object that you can call `.css()` on.

Try `$(articles[1]).css("display", "none");`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WQS47/)

**Edit:** Or even better `articles.eq(1).hide();`

Comment: @Samuel Liew http://jsfiddle.net/WQS47/ seems to work for me.

Comment: @Samuel: Yes you can, but it is unnecessary "complex".

Comment: @Felix I think it is actually easier to understand when explained like this however I totally agree that `articles.eq(1).css('display', none');` is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks andyb, that worked for me too. I went with your suggestion to hide() instead of the css command. I experimented with your first jsfiddle example - worked nicely. In the end I went with .eq(1) - thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This should target the first article

```
var articles = $('article').eq(0);
articles.css({"display":"none"});
```

Check this out for more of an explanation but this does exactly what you need.

http://api.jquery.com/eq/