# Node.js page eval on second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Node.js page eval on second element

```
Below is my code:
/*FetchJP*/ {
    function FetchJP (symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.url = "https://stocks.fetch.demosite.co.jp/stocks/detail/?code=" + encodeURIComponent(this.symbol);
    }

    FetchJP.prototype = Object.create(Scraper.prototype);

    FetchJP.prototype.getValue = async function () {
        return await this.page.$eval('.stoksPrice', e=>e.innerText.trim());
    }
}
```

However because the site itself have 2 class of "stoksPrice", how do I query the second stoksPrice.

```
<table class="stocksTable" summary="株価詳細">
      <tbody><tr>
        <th class="symbol"><h1>Futoka</h1></th>
        <td class="stoksPrice realTimChange">
          <div class="realTimChangeMod">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="stoksPrice">14,045</td>
<td class="change"><span class="yjSt">前日比</span><span class="icoDownRed yjMSt">-235（-1.65%）</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

I'm trying to get the value of **14,045**

How do I modify my code to get the second element of class **stoksPrice**

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I have not use nodejs but maybe this should work : `td.stoksPrice:eq(1)`

Comment: If you want to use jQuery the each function could be used to get both values one at a time.  But $(.stoksPrice).eq(1) would get just the 2nd one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311561/select-element-by-index-multiple-elements-of-same-class

Comment: both i tried seems not working, doesn't fetch the data

Comment: Hi, alone `stoksPrice` this is fetching both class data ? Some other ways check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jk57waqe/)